# Two addEventListener functions on two distinct elements

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I maybe losing my marbles here, but I feel like this is pretty straightforward JavaScript. For some reason, the 1st addEventListener call on the #recipes element is firing the statements in both the 1st and 2nd event handlers, and the 2nd event handler isn't working at all.

```
var recipes = document.getElementById('recipes');
var close_heart = document.getElementById('close_heart');
var recipes_container = document.getElementById('recipes_container');

recipes.addEventListener('click', function(){
  recipes_container.style.display = 'block';
});

close_heart.addEventListener('click', function(){
  recipes_container.style.display = 'none';
});

<div id="recipes"><a href="#" id="close_heart"><span>Recipes</span></a></div>
  <section id="recipes_container"><a href="#" class="fa fa-gittip"></a>
    <h1>Real Mac &amp; Cheese</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Rule #1 &ndash; Use only real cheese (no powdered cheese ever!)</li>
        <li>Rule #2 &ndash; Use multiple cheese-type varieties (ex: sharp cheddar, monterey jack, bleu)</li>
        <li>Rule #3 &ndash; Choose an extra protein like bacon to liven it up!</li>
      </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the html

Comment: I'm too embarrassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without your HTML I can only speculate, but I'd be willing to bet that what you're encountering is event bubbling.

`#recipes` likely encapsulates `#close_heart` such that a `click` on `#close_heart` will bubble up and trigger the `click` event handler for `#recipes` as well.

You can use **[.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)** to resolve this issue. It will prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM and triggering `click` event handlers on parent elements.

```
recipes.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  recipes_container.style.display = 'block';
});

close_heart.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  recipes_container.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Here's another StackOverflow question with a helpful explanation of event capturing and event bubbling: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

**Edit:** Now that you've included your HTML, I can see that is indeed an issue.

Comment: It's the HTML. I was careless. Should I just delete the question?

Comment: Sorry to waste anyone's time.

Comment: @GraySpectrum No, it's a very valid question. Event bubbling is a tricky concept to grasp at first -- or even realize even that event bubbling exists. I'd suggest that you update your question with the HTML snippet for `#recipes` and `#close_heart` to make it more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I simply misplaced an id attribute. The close_heart id should have been placed within the anchor element nested in the section.

Comment: You also have an issue with event bubbling. Any `click` on `#close_heart` will also trigger the `click` event handler for `#recipes`. My answer shows you how to resolve the issue.

Comment: I see. Because the #close_heart element is nested in the #recipes div, so the click event will bubble up by default and trigger the event on the #recipes div. Thanks for persisting with me on this. I have grappled with that concept before, and this example has made it much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing to assign a proper id to the elements. Check the following code, it should work for your case too:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> The Title </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="recipes"> Recipes </button>
        <button id="close_heart"> Close_heart </button>
        <h1 id="recipes_container"> Recipes Container </h1>

        <script>
            var recipes = document.getElementById('recipes');
            var close_heart = document.getElementById('close_heart');
            var recipes_container = 
            document.getElementById('recipes_container');

            recipes.addEventListener('click', function(){
                recipes_container.style.color = "blue";
           });

           close_heart.addEventListener('click', function(){
               recipes_container.style.color = "orange";
           });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Reza. It was that indeed, but there was another issue of event bubbling occurring that Elliot B. was kind enough to point out and explain.